# Combine SQL Select Lines into "Groups"

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, merge

I have the following problem,

I have an audit system, which saves the ID of at most three companies for each Audit onde the database line, but it is possible to have up to 15 companies in an audit.
[image]

Criteria to determine if group audit
IF

1. A record has data in Audited_Company2 AND/OR Audited_Company3
   THEN
   Find additional records where:
2. Auditor_ID AND Audit_Type AND Audit_Date all match the record found above AND
   IF
   Records matching criteria are found:
   1.Take Audited_Company1-3 from all other matching records and insert them into Audited_Company4-15
3. Do not show any audits that have had Audited_Company fields merged into another record in the view

However, I have no idea how to I merge 2 or more SQL Lines n a select result like they asked

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data (or even part of your actual question), sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` to normalize your data and then `PIVOT` to denormalize it again. Below is a sample query that combines the two. It uses `ROW_NUMBER()` with appropriate partitioning and ordering conditions to assign sequence numbers to the data for use in the final pivot.

```
DECLARE @Unnormalized TABLE (Id INT, Value1 VARCHAR(100), Value2 VARCHAR(100), Value3 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Unnormalized
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'B', 'C'),
    (1, 'Z', 'Y', NULL),
    (1, 'X', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 'Red', 'Green', NULL),
    (2, 'Blue', NULL, NULL)

SELECT P.Id, Value1 = P.[1], Value2 = P.[2], P.[3], P.[4], P.[5], P.[6], P.[7], P.[8], P.[9]
FROM (
    SELECT U.Id, U.Value, Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY U.ID ORDER BY U.Value)
    FROM (SELECT * FROM @Unnormalized) D
    UNPIVOT (Value FOR Col IN (Value1, Value2, Value3)) U
) A
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Sequence IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) P
```

Results:

| Id | Value1 | Value2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | X | Y | Z | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Blue | Green | Red | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

You should be able to expand on the above to suit your specific needs.
For more information, take a look at the documentation at [FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).